# Netbeans application (module suite) runs the first time, but does not load later

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

We have a desktop application which is compiled and runs as a Netbeans module suite in Windows environment. When we first install the application, it works fine. But closing the application and trying to start it again does not work - to be specific, the window frame is displayed, but it is completely blank (no windows or menu bar is shown).

At this point, it is not even possible to close the application using the "Close Window" (X) button, but the process has to be stopped using Task Manager.

The same behavior is seen whether the application runs as a desktop application, or whether it is run in Netbeans using "Run Project".

Clearing the application cache (in /AppData/Roaming//dev/var/cache) helps, but the problem repeats next time if the cache is not manually cleared again, so this is not a sustainable solution on client machines.

The application log shows no errors, but stops after

```
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
org.openide.util.lookup [8.22.1 201310111528]
org.openide.util [8.33.1 201310111528]
org.openide.modules [7.39.1 201310111528]
org.openide.filesystems [8.8.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.21.1 201310111528]
org.openide.awt [7.59.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.api.progress/1 [1.35.1 201310111528]
org.openide.dialogs [7.32.1 201310111528]
org.openide.nodes [7.36.1 201310111528]
org.openide.windows [6.65.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup/1 [1.33.1 201310111528]
org.openide.text [6.58.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol [1.46.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.swing.outline [1.27.1 201310111528]
org.openide.explorer [6.53.1 201310111528]
org.openide.actions [6.32.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.queries/1 [1.36.1 201310111528]
org.openide.loaders [7.51.1 201310111528]
org.openide.io [1.42.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.swing.plaf [1.34.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.spi.quicksearch [1.20.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.63.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.51.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.settings/1 [1.42.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.sampler [1.7.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui [1.26.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.keyring [1.17.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core/2 [3.43.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.options.api/1 [1.36.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap [1.28.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.masterfs/2 [2.44.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.libs.jna/1 [1.31.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.windows [1.7.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.keyring.fallback [1.1.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.keyring.impl [1.14.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl/1 [1.24.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.libs.jna.platform/1 [1.1.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.windows/2 [2.66.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.ui/1 [1.38.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.output2/1 [1.34.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.23.1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.multitabs [1.3.3.1 1 201310111528]
org.netbeans.core.io.ui/1 [1.23.1 201310111528]
org.jdesktop [1.0 131217]
<project modules>
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.laf]: USG_LOOK_AND_FEEL
```

For your information, here's the test environment:
Netbeans version: Both 7.3 and 7.4 have the same problem
OS: Windows (tested on various versions)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the ExecutorService calls. We had 3 different asynchronous executors, all scheduled to start at the same time, which somehow resulted in a deadlock. Staggering the start times of the executors fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is connected with this message:

`INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.laf]: USG_LOOK_AND_FEEL`

How do you set up your LAF?

I had a similar problem, but my app hangs only when I run it using desktop shortcut.
I installed it using generated installer (nbm:build-installers).
I found a solution reading a message log (on Linux in: $HOME/user/.bsuit/dev/var/messages.log).